# Starting with FXML - App returns error when changing Label ID and modifying controller accordingly

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm just following some very basic tutorials.
My environment is:
Java 7 oracle SDK
Netbeans 7.3.1
JavaFX SceneBuilder 1.1

I asked the project wizard to produce a first FXML which I called main.

It has a button on it and a label with fx id "label".
When I click on it, the label is set to "Hello, World!".
So far so good.

I want to do something really simple:
Add another label with id "label2" and add the the button event in my controller:
label2.setText("something else");

This however fails.
I don't understand why.
Details:

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="320.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="fs2i.mainController">
  <children>
    <Button id="button" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="165.0" onAction="#handleClickMeButtonAction" text="Say Hi!" />
    <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="72.0" layoutY="120.0" minHeight="16.0" minWidth="69.0" />
    <Label fx:id="label2" layoutX="72.0" layoutY="41.0" prefWidth="88.0" />
    <Button id="Exit" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="165.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleExitButtonAction" text="Exit" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package fs2i;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

/**
 *
 * @author nicolas
 */
public class mainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML 
    private Label label2;

    @FXML
    private void handleClickMeButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
        label2.setText("Something else.");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleExitButtonAction(ActionEvent event){
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
}
```

What it looks like when I click the "Say Hi" button:

[image: JavaFX runtime Hello World]

Logs:

```
You clicked me!
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1449)
```

When I remove iterations of label2 in the controller, everything works again.

Something else that's odd, when I initialize label2 with an initial text "Init", it does not show when I launch the application.

I'm looking for some help to shed some light on what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Seems nothing wrong with code. Try to clean and rebuild the project in Netbeans.

Comment: It's been driving me nuts! It doesn't happen all the time. I've been able to reproduce it somewhat. The thing I see different is that in the XML sometimes an id field shows up id='same as fx:id' and there's the fx:id too..

Trying to remove it doesn't change anything.

I recreated a completely new project, and somehow this time it works.